# How to setup OpenFL (open flash) under MinGW32/MSYS

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am trying to install OpenFL on Windows for MinGW/MSYS (from mingw32.com).

Following OpenFL instructions (http://www.openfl.org/download/), I did:

```
haxelib install lime
haxelib run lime setup
lime install openfl
```

The first two steps went OK. However, the third one failed at first because `lime` cannot be found. After adding `C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe` (which contains `lime.bat`) to windows path, I got the following error:

```
$ lime.bat
/c/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lime.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
Error: '%*' is not a valid command
```

Apparently, the batch file is not for MSYS.

My question is, what steps are necessary to set up lime/openfl to work under MSYS/MinGW32.

Thanks

--EDIT--

as @grapefrukt answer shows, I just needed to replace `lime` with `haxelib run lime`. This also turns out to be the case for other commands shown in the OpenFL documentation if running under MSYS/MinGW. e.g.

```
lime test windows -neko
```

should be replaced with

```
haxelib run lime test windows -neko
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If running haxelib works you should be able to subsitute the last call with this:

```
haxelib run lime install openfl
```

That lime.bat is just a shortcut to save you typing that first part every time.